# No cargan archivos estáticos en Django

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, django, djangorestframework

Tengo un problema con mis archivos estáticos en `django`, no cargan, la carpeta `static` esta en mi `app core` y si se cargan los estilos de los `templates` que están en mi `app core` que extiende de mi `base.html`, pero al momento de extender un `template` de `base.html`que esta en otra `app` de `base.html` no cargan los estilos, los estilos por defecto del `base.html` si cargar pero lo que hay dentro del `{% block content %}` ahí, es donde no hacen efecto los estilos a los elementos, ¿Que esta pasando?

Esta es la estructura de mi proyecto:

```
|── core
|   |── static
|   |   |── core
|   |   |   └── styles.css
|   |   
|   |── templates
|   |   |── core
|   |   |   |── base.html
|   |   |   └─── ...
|
|── coupons
|   |── templates
|   |   |── coupons
|   |   |   └── coupon_list.html
```

Este seria el archivo `base.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'core/css/styles.css' %}">
    <title>WebsiteOfQuotas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'coupons:list' %}">Coupons</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <footer>
        ¡Somos el equipo de WebsiteOfCoupons, para mas informacion contactanos por Gmail en supportWOC@gmail.com! 
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este seria el archivo del que estoy hablando, al que no le cargan los estilos, `coupon_list.html`:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <main>
        {% for coupon in coupon_list %}
            <div class='column'>
                <h2>{{ coupon.title }}</h2>
                <p>{{ coupon.price }}</p>
                <p>{{ coupon.description }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Ya me ha pasado esto antes y no encontré una solución, ¿Sera mejor tener una carpeta `static` propia en la `app coupons`?, ¿Y es de buena practica hacerlo? y ¿Como hay que hacerlo correctamente al momento de cargar los archivos en el elemento `link`? ya que me parece tonto tener que poner todos los estilos `css` de nuevo en el `template`.

Comment: Podrías añadir tu archivo de configuración, más específicamente la parte de STATIC_ROOT y STATIC_URL?

Comment: Acabo de cambiar el nombre del archivo `styles.css` a `main.css` y los `templates` siguen teniendo los estilos `css` acaso es un bug?

Comment: No sabría decirte porque no sé que valor tiene `STATIC_ROOT` y `STATIC_URL`

Comment: No tengo definida la variable `STATIC_ROOT` y el valor de `STATIC_URL` es: `'/static/'`

Comment: Ya leíste la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)? Ahí te explican para qué sirve `STATIC_ROOT` y como funciona todo por defecto. Quizá si dejas todo por defecto y pones tu carpeta de `static` al nivel de `core` puede que soluciones tu problema

Comment: Según leo `STATIC_ROOT` es para el despliegue de la pagina, por cierto ¿Es de buena practica que cada `app` tenga su propia carpeta `static` son sus respectivos archivos estáticos?

Answer (score 1):

deberias tener en settings.py mas o menos asi

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/user/webpersona/static'
```

y tener creada una carpeta static en la raiz de tu project.
espero te sirva
saludos

Comment: Hay que tener siempre definido el `STATIC_ROOT`? Por que e trabajado antes sin definir `STATIC_ROOT` y sin problemas, me puse a investigar sobre `STATIC_ROOT` y no es mejor así? Que opinas?:                     `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

Comment: Va a crearte una carpeta adicional llamada staticfiles luegode hace ``` python manage.py collecstatic```